# Empty request body in delete method node.ls react axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I have problem, when I send delete request to server using axios my body of request is empty, but with same code in post method it works.
In postman delete method is working

Here id isn't empty

```
export const deleteClothes = async (id) => {
    id.id = Number(id.id)
    const {data} = await $authHost.delete('api/clothes', id)
    return data
}
```

But here, req.body is empty

```
async delete(req, res) {
    const{id} = req.body
    await Clothes.destroy({
        where:{
            id: id
        }
    })
    return res.json(`Clothes deleted: ${id}`)
}
```

The same post method:

```
export const createType = async (type) => {
    const {data} = await $authHost.post('api/type', type)
    return data
}
```

Idk what to do, I've tried a lot of things

Comment: Have you tried put id in an explicit config parameter like this: `$authHost.delete("/api/clothes", {data:  id}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we review [the API documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro), we can see that the signature of the `post` method is `axios.post(url[, data[, config]])`, but the signature of the `delete` method is `axios.delete(url[, config])` — notice that the second argument is a config object, not a request body as it is with `post`. You're passing the object you want used as the body directly as the config object.

Instead, pass a config object with a `data` property:

```
const {data} = await $authHost.delete('api/clothes', {data: id})
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

Side note: It's confusing to have the `deleteClothes` parameter called `id` that's an object with an `id` property on it. In the code above, `id` is the object, which seems to be what you want given your `post` example. I'd suggest renaming the parameter to something reflecting what that *object* is (a clothing item or whatever).

Comment: Thank you so much, I will take note of your remark

Answer (score 0):

the DELETE method is not intended to have a request body coz not all requests have body. Instead you should include the information you want to delete in the query string or as a path parameter in the URL. for example api/clothes/clothID

Comment: const {data} = await $authHost.delete(`api/clothes/${id}`)

Comment: *"the DELETE method is not intended to have a request body"* That's incorrect. `DELETE` can have a body. Sometimes you need to send so much information to identify the resource to delete that you can't use a query string for it. More [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/DELETE).